# The Go Server service on Local Computer started and then stopped

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-delivery, go-cd

I am trying to install GoCD Server 19.1.0 64 bit on my Windows 10 64 bit machine. Installation went through without any issue, however, I am getting the following error on starting Go Server service.

I tried to run service under Local System Account as well as specific admin account but not luck so far.

I also tried setting NoInteractiveServices registry from 1 to 0 (at \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows) but still getting the same error.

Please let me know if any of you have faced this error and know the solution.

---

### Services

### The Go Server service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

### OK

Thanks in advance,

ND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @moritz for the info. I did not find any files under logs folder as it was failing with Access Denied error while writing to logs files. Not sure what was the reason behind that but this is how I fixed it.

I re installed the Go Server, this time I have selected C:\Program Files (instead of default C:\Program Files (x86)) and selected Open Java instead of providing path of JRE installed locally.

This worked in my case, however, feel free to let me know if you see any problem in this approach.

ND

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [GoCD's Log files](https://docs.gocd.org/current/advanced_usage/logging.html) to find out what happened, and why GoCD stopped.